# How to automatically display definition of post title?

Tags: php, wordpress

For every post I have in Wordpress I would like it to automatically take the post title and display a definition if no content has been typed in already.

So if I create a new post called "Dog" and I do not give that post any content, WordPress will automatically generate a definition to place in the content like "a domesticated carnivorous mammal that typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking, howling, or whining voice. It is widely kept as a pet or for work or field sports."

If no plugin exists for this sort of approach I am comfortable writing it myself.

Would Wikipedia or Google Define be best for this situation if so?

Comment: wikipedia api will work for you!!

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!

Comment: and what if the post ends up being about a certain reality tv bounty hunter?

Comment: The post will look up that certain reality tv bounty hunter and give its best definition for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wordpress hook [save post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) . And then you can use any API that you want

Comment: So after the post is created it could go out and fetch a wikipedia definition based on the title and auto populate the post content?

Comment: Yes then you can just use `get_post($post_id)` and then [Update Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) with the content returned from the API

Comment: This sounds perfect but it is a bit beyond my capabilities at the moment.